# Which way to get indices of collection items meeting a condition is better?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Suppose I have a collection of strings.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt"));
```

And a regular expression to search for a match in that collection:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"some regular expression");
```

How can I get the indeces of elements, matching the regex?

I have three ideas.

---

1st:

```
var indeces1 = lines.Where(l => r.IsMatch(l))
                    .Select(l => lines.IndexOf(l));
foreach (int i in indeces1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);//Do the index-based task instead...
}
```

What I don't like about it, is using `IndexOf` over the original collection. Am I wrong and it's OK?

---

```
var indeces2 = lines.Select((l, i) => new { Line = l, Index = i })
                    .Where(o => r.IsMatch(o.Line));

foreach (var o in indeces2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.Index);//Do the index-based task instead...
}
```

It seems to be better than the 1st one, but is there a way to do the same thing without creating an anonymous object?

---

And the last one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    if (r.IsMatch(lines[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);//Do the index-based task instead...
    }
}
```

Actually I have this one working now. But as I do love LINQ, I wanted to have a LINQ way to do the same.

So is there a better LINQ way to do this simple task?

Comment: If you just need indices then why don't you try `.Select(t => t.Index);` in your option 2. *(at the end)* to get `IEnumerable<int>`  of indices only. You will get rid of the Anonymous object

Comment: @Habib it's worth to be an answer here as well as Cuong Le's post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you love LINQ, you can use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) for simpler:

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, lines.Count)
                        .Where(i => r.IsMatch(lines[i]));
```

**Edit:**

Instead of using `File.ReadAllLines` to get all lines into memory:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt"));
```

If your file is large, you should consider to use [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which is deferred execution for more efficient:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Test.txt"));
```

Comment: +1: always forget about `Enumerable.Range`...thanks for `File.ReadLines` I'll consider using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need indices then why don't you try .Select(t => t.Index); in your option 2. *(at the end)* to get IEnumerable of indices only. You will get rid of the Anonymous object.

So your query would be:

```
var indeces2 = lines.Select((l, i) => new { Line = l, Index = i })
        .Where(o => r.IsMatch(o.Line))
        .Select(t => t.Index);
```

Comment: +1: Actually your comment gave me this idea (very close to what Cuong Le showed): `lines.Select((l, i) => i).Where(i => r.IsMatch(lines[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would go with your humble iterator version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    if (r.IsMatch(lines[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);//Do the index-based task instead...
    }
}
```

For this scenario, LINQ does not really reduce the line count and increase readability, in comparisson to option 3. So I would go for the simplest version in this case.